# Is it possible to convexify this cone constraint?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

#### General question

An SOCP constraint is given by:

$$ \| A_i \mathbf{x} + b_i\| \leq \mathbf{c}_i^T \mathbf{x} + d_i.$$

I have the following constraint:

$$ \| A_i \mathbf{x} \| \geq d_i.$$

Is it possible to apply some kind of trick to convexify this constraint?

#### The specific case for which convexification might be possible?

In my problem, the constraint aims at avoiding subsurface flight of a vehicle in orbit by dictating that the norm of the vehicle's radius vector must always be larger than the radius of the planet, e.g.:

$$\|\mathbf{r} \| \geq R,$$

where $\mathbf{r}$ is the radius vector and $R$ is the planet's radius. Is it possible to apply some trick and make this constraint convex in this case?

#### PS:

I am aware of [question 619727](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619727/socp-formulation-wrong-inequality-direction-in-constraints), but that is a slightly different case

Comment: Your case actually fits exactly in question 619727....

Comment: Well I thought that there might be a trick to rewrite the constraint... if there is not, please just close this question, or I will delete it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SOCP formulation: wrong inequality direction in constraints](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619727/socp-formulation-wrong-inequality-direction-in-constraints)

Comment: Would you post the complete optimization problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *mathematical* trick to convexify a constraint like that. *It's the complement of a convex set*. That's about as "far" from convex as you can get with a connected set.

That said, it might be possible for you to find a way to modify your *model* so that it is more readily handled using convex optimization. You might look at the work of [Dr. Behcet Acikmese](http://behcet.ae.utexas.edu/) at the University of Texas. He's written papers on the "convexification" of certain convex models involved in guidance, navigation, and control problems.

[Here is a PDF](http://web.mit.edu/larsb/www/AcikmeseBlackmoreACC10.pdf) of one of his conference papers, which he co-wrote with [Lars Blackmore](http://web.mit.edu/larsb/www/). It might be a good place to start. I make no guarantees that it will apply to your application. [Here](http://web.mit.edu/larsb/www/losslessconvexification.htm) is a longer list of papers by Blackmore et al on the use of convex optimization for guidance, navigation, and control.